# Need help sorting large Numpy matrix by column and then iterating through the columns. Argsort seems too slow

Tags: python, columnsorting, numpy-slicing

I am new to python and could use help in sorting a very large np array, slicing the top k rows, then adding up the final column.

I can make it work in with argsort, but it is way to slow as I scale up. Here is what I have done.

I start with a basic array.

```
sim=np.array([[0.76, 0.7, 0.47, 0.28, 0.62],
 [0.47, 0.47, 0.6,  0.23, 0.52],
 [0.44, 0.03, 0.25, 0.6,  0.14],
 [0.46, 0.48, 0.43, 0.92, 0.98],
 [0.86, 0.94, 0.67, 0.4,  0.42],
 [0.54, 0.48, 0.28, 0.71, 0.6 ]])
```

Then add a scoring column.

output:

```
array([[ 0.76,  0.7 ,  0.47,  0.28,  0.62,  1.  ],
       [ 0.47,  0.47,  0.6 ,  0.23,  0.52,  1.  ],
       [ 0.44,  0.03,  0.25,  0.6 ,  0.14, -1.  ],
       [ 0.46,  0.48,  0.43,  0.92,  0.98, -1.  ],
       [ 0.86,  0.94,  0.67,  0.4 ,  0.42,  1.  ],
       [ 0.54,  0.48,  0.28,  0.71,  0.6 , -1.  ]])
```

Then iterate through the columns and take the top 3 values, summing those values. I want to be able to iterate through thousands of columns and do this.

Output:

```
[[ 0.86  0.94  0.67  0.4   0.42  1.  ]
 [ 0.76  0.7   0.47  0.28  0.62  1.  ]
 [ 0.54  0.48  0.28  0.71  0.6  -1.  ]] 1.0 

[[ 0.86  0.94  0.67  0.4   0.42  1.  ]
 [ 0.76  0.7   0.47  0.28  0.62  1.  ]
 [ 0.54  0.48  0.28  0.71  0.6  -1.  ]] 1.0 

[[0.86 0.94 0.67 0.4  0.42 1.  ]
 [0.47 0.47 0.6  0.23 0.52 1.  ]
 [0.76 0.7  0.47 0.28 0.62 1.  ]] 3.0 

[[ 0.46  0.48  0.43  0.92  0.98 -1.  ]
 [ 0.54  0.48  0.28  0.71  0.6  -1.  ]
 [ 0.44  0.03  0.25  0.6   0.14 -1.  ]] -3.0 

[[ 0.46  0.48  0.43  0.92  0.98 -1.  ]
 [ 0.76  0.7   0.47  0.28  0.62  1.  ]
 [ 0.54  0.48  0.28  0.71  0.6  -1.  ]] -1.0
```

This all works find on a smallish array, but once I get over 10,000 x 10,000 it starts to grind to a halt and I need to go even bigger.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `numpy.argsort` has an `axis` argument that lets you sort along any axis, including iterating the "columns," so that could make your code a bit cleaner. Also maybe consider either refactoring as iterating rows, or making a F-contiguous array where data in columns are contiguous.

Comment: Can you provide a more simple example of input and desired output?

Comment: I figured out my main issue. The score array that I was appending was an integer in my original program. Interesting, when I created this example, the score became float. Anyway, the mixed type of the np array seemed to be the problem. I did an astype(float) to the score array and now it is iterating a 19,000 row column about ever second. I have some ideas to further improve performance, but it was taking 10 minutes or more for a single iteration prior to this fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do that, based on [`numpy.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html). (You haven't shown how you are currently doing the calculation, so we can't check relative performance.)

Because the scoring data seems to be semantically different from the data in `sim`, it probably makes sense to keep it in a separate array.  I'll use these arrays in an example:

```
In [32]: sim
Out[32]: 
array([[0.76, 0.7 , 0.47, 0.28, 0.62],
       [0.47, 0.47, 0.6 , 0.23, 0.52],
       [0.44, 0.03, 0.25, 0.6 , 0.14],
       [0.46, 0.48, 0.43, 0.92, 0.98],
       [0.86, 0.94, 0.67, 0.4 , 0.42],
       [0.54, 0.48, 0.28, 0.71, 0.6 ]])

In [33]: score
Out[33]: array([ 1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1])
```

First, use `numpy.argpartition` to find the indices of the three largest elements in each column of `sim`. Since `argpartition` is based on finding the *smallest* elements, I'll apply it to `-sim`:

```
In [34]: p = np.argpartition(-sim, 3, axis=0)

In [35]: p
Out[35]: 
array([[4, 4, 1, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 4, 5, 0],
       [5, 5, 0, 2, 5],
       [1, 3, 3, 4, 1],
       [3, 1, 5, 0, 4],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]])

In [36]: p3 = p[:3]

In [37]: p3
Out[37]: 
array([[4, 4, 1, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 4, 5, 0],
       [5, 5, 0, 2, 5]])
```

`p3` holds the indices of the three largest elements in each column.

Now index `score` with `p3` to create an array containing the corresponding scores for the indices in `p3`:

```
In [39]: scores = score[p3]

In [40]: scores
Out[40]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1, -1, -1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, -1,  1],
       [-1, -1,  1, -1, -1]])
```

Then add up the columns to get the final scores:

```
In [41]: scores.sum(axis=0)
Out[41]: array([ 1,  1,  3, -3, -1])
```

Here's the calculation expressed more concisely:

```
In [42]: p = np.argpartition(-sim, 3, axis=0)

In [43]: score[p[:3]].sum(axis=0)
Out[43]: array([ 1,  1,  3, -3, -1])
```